# PHPのヒアドキュメント内のSQLのプレースホルダの挙動が，? と :name で何故か異なる

Tags: php, mysql

### 問題の要約

PHPを使って，次のようなものを作ろうとしています．

- 入力フォームでユーザからの入力を受け付ける．
- データベースから，ユーザからの入力に合致するようなデータをSQLで取り出す
- 取り出したデータをPHPで表示する

より具体的に言うと，`Customers`というテーブルがあって，そこに`requestID`というカラムがあります．ユーザが入力フォームから検索して，あるrequestIDを持つようなレコードがあるかどうか検索することができるようにしたいです．

そこで，SQL文をどのようにするかで困っています．

プレースホルダを使って

```sql
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        Customers
    WHERE 
        requestID = :requestID
```

というSQLを実行し，PHP側で

```php
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam('requestID', $_POST['requestID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
```

という処理を行うことを最初は検討しましたが，これだとユーザ入力が空の時に「requestIDが空であるようなレコード」が検索されてしまいます．

ユーザ入力が空だったときには，「絞り込みは行わない」というふうにしたいです．

まずCASE文とヒアドキュメントを使って，次のようなSQLを書いてみました．

```sql
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        Customers
    WHERE 
        requestID = 
        CASE
            WHEN :requestID = '' THEN
                requestID
            ELSE
                :requestID
        END
    SQL;
```

これならユーザ入力のポスト変数が空文字だったときには，全件検索になります．

しかし，これを実行して

```php
$sth->bindParam('requestID', $_POST['requestID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

を行うとエラーになってしまい，`エラー: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number` というエラーメッセージが出ます．

しかしながら `:requestID` という書き方をやめて `?` で書き直し，全体を

```php
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        Customers
    WHERE 
        requestID = 
        CASE
            WHEN ? = '' THEN
                requestID
            ELSE
                ?
        END
    SQL;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(1, $_POST['requestID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $_POST['requestID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
```

と書き直すと今度は正常に動きます．

これはいったいどういうことでしょうか？なぜ `:name` 式の書き方だとエラーになってしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: そもそも変数に入れるのであれば、ヒアドキュメントを利用しないでSQL文をstring型で組み立てていき、requestIDがあったらWhere条件を追記&バインド追加するという方法でやればいいと思います。[参考](https://qiita.com/kouyan/items/0bf88b3ffa01b77e86ed#%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B61--1%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．誤解があると思うのですが，訊きたいことはヒアドキュメント使用の是非ではなくて， :name を使用するとなぜエラーになるのかです

Comment: 質問の意図は理解しております。ですが、やりたいことはクライアントのrequestidの有無で発行するSQLを変えれば、ヒアドキュメントやcase文の利用する前提でプログラムを組むことが必要ないのではという疑問でした。

Comment: なるほど．次にSQLを書く時には参考にします．